# Terraform Enterprise Postgresql setup, no connection

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-enterprise

I have followed the documentation for Terraform Enterprise setup with GCP - External Services.

When I start up the TerraformEnterprise application in browser having configured it with the Hostname:Port and additional information the application will build then "waiting for app to report ready" until it eventually times out.

As per TFE documentation, the ComputeInstance with TFE Application is a private instance, managed by InstanceGroup behind a Load Balancer.
This all works as it should.

Unsure as to why the Postgres connection is non existent.
Any help would be appreciated.

Built the PrivateInstance and deployed TFE Application (working)
Built the Postgresql instance and configured the DB instance in Browser as the TFE Documentation suggests.

Run application - It builds but doesn't report as ready so times out.